# yii controller filters() method pattern

Tags: filter, yii

every controller should have method filters(), there you can specify some classes, i want to know, how those classes are include by framework ? how those classes are configuring, and when, and maybe someone can give me a pattern for this way of using filters() and including some classes ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The controller filters are classes deriving from [`CFilter`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CFilter).

As the [documentation example](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/basics.controller#filter) shows, you configure them inside your controller like this:

```
public function filters()
    {
        return array(
            'postOnly + edit, create',
            array(
                'application.filters.PerformanceFilter - edit, create',  // 1
                'unit'=>'second',                                        // 2
                'amount'=>42,                                            // 3
            ),
        );
    }
```

In the line marked `1` you provide the path for the hypothetical class `PerformanceFilter`; Yii loads that as any other component.

In the line marked `2` and `3` you initialize properties. You can go on with any number of key/value pairs; they will all get used to set the filter's properties with the corresponding names.